# Value of member of composite class using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class which compose of multiple other classes.

```
class X
{
    public string str;
}

class Y
{
    public X x;
}
```

Now I know that using reflection you can get the value a direct member of `class Y` but my doubt is that whether using reflection, can I get the value of member of composite class i.e. str? Something like `y.GetType().GetProperty("x.str")`

I have also tried `y.GetType().GetNestedType("X")`  but it is giving me null as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something like `y.GetType().GetProperty("x.str")`

No, this is not going to work. You need to get property `x`, [get its type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype.aspx), then get the property of that other type:

```
y.GetType().GetProperty("x").PropertyType.GetProperty("str");
```

Of course for this to work you need to make `x` and `str` properties, not fields. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/n0MV4m).

> I have also tried `y.GetType().GetNestedType("X")` but it is giving me null as output.

That is because `GetNestedType` gives you a type defined inside `Y`, like this:

```
class Y {
    class X { // <<= This is a nested type
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, I have to specify `x.str` as a parameter in form of annotations. So do you know what is the best way to specify this kind of thing in an annotation? Here `x.str` is an example of two level member, it can be three level or in general n level deep.

Comment: `y.GetType().GetProperty("x")` is also giving null output.

Comment: @RaviGupta That's because there are no properties in your test classes: `x` and `str` are fields. Make them properties, and it will work. Take a look at the demo I linked in the edit.

Comment: @RaviGupta You would need to split the name on the dots, and go through the list in a loop.

Comment: But it is returning only the type i.e. `{System.String str}`. Now when I'm doing `y.GetType().GetProperty("x").PropertyType.GetProperty("str").GetValue(???, null)` what should I pass in place of ???.

Comment: If I pass `y', it throws an `TargetException` i.e. `{"Object does not match target type."}`

Comment: @RaviGupta You cannot pass `y` to that property, because it's a property of `X`. You need to follow the trail of objects in the same way that you followed the trail of types, i.e. pull the value of `x` property from the `y` object, then give that object to the `str` property to access the actual value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38269/discussion-between-ravi-gupta-and-dasblinkenlight)

Answer (score 0):

You use the nested properties type:

```
y.x.GetType().GetProperty("str").GetValue(y.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression trees to statically retrieve the `PropertyInfo`. This also has the advantage of not working with strings, which supports easier refactoring.

```
ExpressionHelper.GetProperty(() => y.x.str);

public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        PropertyInfo property = null;
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberExpression != null)
        {
            property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        }

        if (property == null) throw new ArgumentException("Expression does not contain a property accessor", "expression");

        return property;
    }
}
```